# E.hasMorePage VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Al imprimir etiquetas en un PrintDocument, no me muestra la segunda página, pero al ejecutarlo lo que he visto se entra en un bucle en el que no consigo sacarlo. Está es la función en la que cargo el Printdocument con las etiquetas.

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        Dim x As Integer = 40
        Dim y As Integer = 40
        Dim image As Image
        Dim barcode As Barcode = New Barcode()
        Dim write As New BarcodeWriter
        Dim codigo As Image
        Dim rows As List(Of DataGridViewRow) = (From item In Me.dgv.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()).ToList
        Dim valor As String
        Dim conteo As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In rows

            valor = "090" + row.Cells("colNHC").Value.ToString.Trim
            write.Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128
            picBarcode.Image = write.Write(valor)
            image = write.Write(valor)
            codigo = picBarcode.Image
            If conteo >= 2 Then
                y += 4
            End If
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(codigo, y, x, anchoCodigo, altoCodigo)
            pegatinas += 1
            y = y + anchoCodigo + 20
            If conteo > 3 Then
                y += 30
            End If
            conteo += 1
            If conteo.Equals(5) Then
                conteo = 0
                x += 87
                y = 40
            End If
            If (pegatina >= 65) Then
               ****
                e.HasMorePages = True
                pegatinas = 0
                x = 40
                y = 40
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

***aquí cuento las veces que pongo una etiqueta en el printdocument y entra pero la función se vuelve a llamar y no entiendo porque.*

Muchas Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Cada vez que el código llame a PrintDocument1.Print() se ejecutará  PrintDocument1_PrintPage. Si por un casual PrintDocument1.Print() está en un bucle, el procedimiento PrintDocument1_PrintPage se llamará tantas veces como se repita el bucle.

Mira la siguiente discusión traducida del inglés a ver si te puede ayudar en algo [aquí](https://stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/16422965/vb-net-printing-error-print-printpage-continues-to-loop-even-though-e-hasmorepa?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=es&_x_tr_pto=wapp) Si te parece me comentas.

Comment: La llamada al evento, no lo tengo en ningún bucle. He creado las variables fuera de la función del evento, ahora si consigue crearme una segunda página pero no me envía los datos a esta.

Comment: Por favor, mira el enlace que he añadido en mi comentario por si te puede servir de ayuda.